# Is there any way to use OrmLite with Postgres hstores?

Tags: java, postgresql, ormlite

We're currently using a PostgreSQL database and OrmLite. We now have a use case for using an [Postgres hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html), but can't find any way of accessing that table through OrmLite. I'd prefer to avoid opening a separate database connection just to select and insert to that one table, but I'm not seeing any other options.

At the very least I'd like a handle to the existing connection OrmLite is using so I can reuse it to build a prepared statement, but I haven't found a way to get a `java.sql.Connection` starting from an OrmLite ConnectionSource`.`

I see that OrmLite has a `JdbcCompiledStatement`, but that's just a wrapper around a `PreparedStatement` and requires the `PreparedStatement` to be passed in to the constructor. (Not sure what the use case for that is.)

I've tried to use `DatabaseConnection.compileStatement(...)`, but that requires knowledge of the field types being used and OrmLite doesn't seem to know what an hstore is.

I've tried to use `updateRaw()`, but that function only exists on an OrmLite dao that I don't have because the table I would link the dao to has a field type OrmLite doesn't recognize. Is there some way to get a generic dao to issue raw queries?

I get that hstores are database specific and probably won't be supported by OrmLite, but I'd really like to find a way to transfer data to and from the database using unsupported fields instead of just unsupported queries.

Comment: +1 for trying so much stuff Tim.  I'd not heard of hstores before now.  let me do some reading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At the very least I'd like a handle to the existing connection OrmLite is using so I can reuse it to build a prepared statement...

Ok, that's pretty easy.  As @jsight mentioned, the [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) `ConnectionSource` for JDBC is `JdbcConnectionSource`.  When you get a connection from that class using `connectionSource.getReadOnlyConnection()`, you will get a `DatabaseConnection` that is really a `JdbcDatabaseConnection` and can be cast to it.  There is a [`JdbcDatabaseConnection.getInternalConnection()`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-jdbc/com/j256/ormlite/jdbc/JdbcDatabaseConnection.html#getInternalConnection%28%29) method which returns the associated `java.sql.Connection`.

> I've tried to use updateRaw(), but that function only exists on an OrmLite dao that I don't have ...

You really can use any DAO class to perform a raw function on any table.  It is convenient to think of it as being an unstructured update to an DAO object's table.  But if you have any DAO, you can perform a raw update on any other table.

> find a way to transfer data to and from the database using unsupported fields instead of just unsupported queries

If you are using unsupported fields, then you are going to have to do it as a raw statement -- either `SELECT` or `UPDATE`.  If you edit your post to show the raw statement you've tried, I can help more specifically.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that updateRaw wasn't available on my dao. What I meant is that I don't have a dao, because I can't annotate  the field in my class that is represented in the database with an hstore. Without class annotations, there is no dao. As far as I know. I don't quite understand why issuing raw queries is done at the dao level. The query could be joining multiple tables together, or accessing a completely different table than the dao implies, correct?

Comment: Good point @Tim.  People use ORMLite to store Accounts in a database.  Sometimes they need to do unstructured queries hence the raw query method on a Dao although really you can use _any_ DAO to do the query.  Also, the DAO has a lot of database connection code that needs to be used.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like ConnectionSource may actually be implemented by JdbcConnectionSource, and will likely return a JdbcDatabaseConnection. That object has a getInternalConnection method that looks like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

@Gray I submitted an ORMLite patch on SourceForge that can enables the "Other" data type.  The patch ID is 3566779.  With this patch, it's possible to support hstores.

Users will need to add the PGHStore class to their projects.  The code for this class is [here](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-jdbc/2009-12/msg00037.php.).

Users will also need to add a persister class as shown here:

```
package com.mydomain.db.persister;

import com.mydomain.db.PGHStore;
import com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType;
import com.j256.ormlite.field.SqlType;
import com.j256.ormlite.field.types.BaseDataType;
import com.j256.ormlite.support.DatabaseResults;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class PGHStorePersister extends BaseDataType {

    private static final PGHStorePersister singleton = new PGHStorePersister();

    public static PGHStorePersister getSingleton() {
        return singleton;
    }

    protected PGHStorePersister() {
        super(SqlType.OTHER, new Class<?>[] { PGHStore.class });
    }

    protected PGHStorePersister(SqlType sqlType, Class<?>[] classes) {
        super(sqlType, classes);
    }

    @Override
    public Object parseDefaultString(FieldType ft, String string) throws SQLException {
        return new PGHStore(string);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resultToSqlArg(FieldType fieldType, DatabaseResults results, int columnPos) throws SQLException {
        return results.getString(columnPos);
    }

    @Override
    public Object sqlArgToJava(FieldType fieldType, Object sqlArg, int columnPos) throws SQLException {
        return new PGHStore((String) sqlArg);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAppropriateId() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Lastly, users will need to annotate their data to use the persister.

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "myData", persisterClass=PGHStorePersister.class)
```

Comment: The patch mentioned above will be included in version 4.42 of ORMLite.