# Using PostGIS with ormLite

Tags: java, jdbc, postgis, ormlite

I connected ormlite with jdbc to a postgresql database. My datastructure is predefined and contains a Postgis datatype called geometry. This datatype can contain different geometry structures (point, line string, polygon, ...) for GIS-Applications. Natively Postgis can convert this datatype to geoJson or any other stringtyped gis-related format.

When I directly use ormLite with Postgis (as a String) it gives me a binary-format. So I would like to use a postgis-function to convert this binary-format to e.g. geoJson, KML.

In SQL it looks like this:

```
select ST_AsGeoJson(geometrycolumn) from table;
```

or

```
update table set geometrycolumn = ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-5.5,7.2]}')
```

In the model this geometry column should be accessed (read/write) as a String.

I tried to use ormlite persisters but this is too late. At this time, persister are used (through `resultToSqlArg` or `parseDefaultString`), the query was sent to the database and I cannot edit the columns which are requested from postgres. [Mrog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1664198/mrog) had a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12378846/2050564) for a problem which is related to this but used also persisters.

I also tried override the specific classes with jdbc. But don't know how to "inject" sql-functions.

Or I could use raw-SQL queries. But there are a lot of other attributes in the table I need to use. And I have to use two Queries to the database (One time for regular attributes and one time for the geometry column). And my sense of an orm is not to use raw sql statements.

Another solution would be to create a geoJson-column on database side. ormLite could read from this and write with a sql-trigger to the original column. But thats a poor solution.

Do I really have to create a custom datatype and make the conversion on serverside instead of doing it on the database? Or is there a solution to use the native database functions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to get this sorted out although with a slightly different setup. I've been focusing on getting Polygons that are in WKT from inside MSSQL.

Seeing as i'm only using Rectangles I decided to make a Rectangle datatype. This works fine on the inserts and updates due to [javaToSqlArg](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/BaseFieldConverter.html#javaToSqlArg%28com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType,%20java.lang.Object%29) as my implementation is returning

```
return String.format("geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((%d %d, %d %d, %d %d, %d %d, %d %d))',0)",etc...)
```

Which leaves selects as the problem. The only way I found of fixing this was a little dirty.

I created another column in the table as the String based representation of the geometry types. Then I added a trigger to keep them in sync. When one updates the other gets converted and updated.

If i didnt use the databases geometry functions for intersects etc. I would probably just make the field Text.

It might also be worthwhile to take a look at: [WKB4J](http://wkb4j.sourceforge.net/) it might be able to read the binary data returned from ormlite and make them more tangible.