# How to backup in memory database or restore memory database from file?

Tags: backup, ormlite

I use ORMLite and SQLite in memory database for speed. After operation, I need to backup the in memory database to a file, but could's find a method to do that.

In another thread ([Backup and restore sqlite from disk to memory in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548026)) shown a method with JDBC Connection, therefor my question can be narrowed down to: **If I have had a ORMLite ConnectionSource object, how can I get a JDBC Connection object from it?**

Thanks

Comment: I found a useful thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374848/is-there-any-way-to-use-ormlite-with-postgres-hstores; simple as : JdbcDatabaseConnection.getInternalConnection();

Comment: backup works fine: `(JdbcDatabaseConnection) getSharedConnectionSource().getReadWriteConnection().getInternalConnection().createStatement().executeUpdate("backup to data.db");`; <p>however, restore doesn't work: `jdbcDatabaseConnection = (JdbcDatabaseConnection) getSharedConnectionSource().getReadWriteConnection().getInternalConnection().createStatement().executeUpdate("restore from data.db");`

Comment: "Restore" doesn't work because SQLite doesn't support connection pool (JdbcPooledConnectionSource) for in-memory mode...I think. Using JdbcConnectionSource  does then restoring job.

Comment: Problem solved!. Connecting string `"jdbc:sqlite:file::memory:?cache=shared"` solved it.